# Get 18.04 LTS screen lock behaviour in 20.04

Tags: 20.04, lock-screen

I've recently upgraded to 20.04 LTS. In the previous LTS, after 10 mins of no activity, the screen would lock. A little after it would power down the screen. This let my monitor go into power save mode. However, I could type my password while the screen was still off and it would be coming back on as I unlocked.

Now I have to wait those few seconds so that I can see some sort of lock screen (black with the word Ubuntu on the bottom) to go away before I am back to the lock screen and can type my password to start using my computer again.

How do I get the old LTS screen behaviour in 20.04?

Comment: Personally I did not notice any change in lock screen behaviour between versions. And for me on 20.04 and 20.10 I can always resume from lock screen by just typing the password. No other keypresses or waiting. If you are seeing black screen with ubuntu logo on the bottom it sounds like your PC is going into suspend not just locking. So the first keypress wakes the PC, you see the logo and have to wait to come out of suspend and only then can you enter your password. Have you got `Automatic Suspend` on in your power settings?

Comment: Good question. I will look.

Comment: Yes, I do. I turned it off. Must have changed when the update happened.